# How to put form input into html file via php?

Tags: html

I have this html file:

```
<div>
    <div class="input">
        <img src="2017-01-10.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        Some text here
    </div>
    <div class="input">
       January 10th 2017
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to make an input form (in another page) that add a div like that, above it.

So the user can fill the form with an image, a text and a date and when submit that will add to the html file above a code like that but with a new input.

In the end the code would be like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="input">
        <img src="2017-01-11.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        Some text here
    </div>
    <div class="input">
       January 11th 2017
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="input">
        <img src="2017-01-10.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        Some text here
    </div>
    <div class="input">
       January 10th 2017
    </div>
</div>
```

What would I put into the php file of the form?
Is that possible for php to write permanently into the html file?

Comment: You can insert form data in database and call it in html page using while loop

Comment: [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) Is always the first place to start

Comment: "What would I put into the php file of the form?" — You need to start with an introductory PHP tutorial and not with Stackoverflow. (Well, you can start with [the tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) and use it to find a suitable tutorial).

Comment: "Is that possible for php to write permanently into the html file?" — Possible, but a terrible idea. Use a database.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I will try to learn some php and Mysql

Answer (score 1):

You need to process the user input to an SQL database. The user input will then be stored in the .html file permanently. But you're not done there, you also have to add a `.htaccess` file to your site to parse PHP into HTML.

To learn how to save the user input from PHP to an SQL database watch this [video](https://youtu.be/OYBkkozuc5Q).
And to learn how to use `.htaccess` watch this [video](https://youtu.be/ka5m_kvQUFo).